# tomcat 7: automatically redirect https requests to port 8443

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, tomcat7, server.xml

On tomcat7, our web application is running through https over port `8443` and works fine except that we are unable to redirect https default port (`443`) to `8443` so as a consequence the ':8443' has to be included in the URL whenever we have to access the application.
I include some parts of our server.xml file. What should be done in order to be able to load our pages without having to enter port information in the URL?

```xml
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="8443" />
...

<Connector port="8443"
            maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
            scheme="https"
            secure="true"
            SSLEnabled="true"
            clientAuth="false"
            enableLookups="true"
            acceptCount="100"
            disableUploadTimeout="true"
            maxThreads="200"
            sslProtocol="TLS"
            keystoreFile="/toto/has/a/certificate.jks"
            keystorePass="totohasapassword"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />
```

Comment: found a simple solution on coderanch using iptables:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/601907/Tomcat/SSL-work

Here is the line to enter:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443

Comment: is it possible that port number remains the same and only it redirects to https?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a simple solution on coderanch using iptables: http://coderanch.com/t/601907/Tomcat/SSL-work

Here is the line to enter:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

#### New edit

Here is my complete answer now. We had a problem with the previous answer as when we were calling the url from http, the redirection was ok but was always adding ':8443' at the end which was not very nice.

So in terms of iptable, here is what we wrote:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <your_ip_address>,<your_ip_address>  --dport 80 -j  REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

Now also important is to add redirections in tomcat conf file *server.xml*:

```xml
<Connector port="8080"
           enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

That's it, restart tomcat and all should be working. I'm not an expert in iptable configurations so please validate with sysadmins before modifying any existing config in production.

Comment: @engineer not sure i understand what you're asking. Protocol is "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" and this value is still right for me at least.

Comment: again, i'm not a tomcat expert so don't take my answer as final. The firsts connectors are only there to redirect tomcat to 8443 no matter what and the default protocol for a normal connector is HTTP/1.1 (indeed HTTP/ was not the default and probably wrong). Once you enable SSL, it won't work with HTTP/1.1 and protocol Http11NioProtocol will work and be able to understand the tls communication

Comment: Did anyone actually test the iptables ruleset? Why is "your_ip_address" in there twice? Also, why can't we redirect port 80 to say, 8443 in iptables and then have only one connector in Tomcat? Does Tomcat need a non-ssl connector?

Comment: is it possible that port number remains the same and only it redirects to https?